# Composing with a function + constant

Tags: calculus, function-and-relation-composition

Consider the discounting condition in the Blackwell's sufficient conditions:

(Reference: [A related question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/25154/in-blackwells-condition-for-t-to-be-a-contraction-mapping-we-require-that-sati)).

There exists some $\beta \in (0, 1)$ such that $[T(f + a)](x) ≤ (T f)(x) + βa$, for all $f ∈ B(X), a ≥ 0, x ∈ X$.

Here $f$ is a function from a space of bounded functions and $a$ is a positive constant. Without the positive constant, I obtain:

$$(Tf)(x)=b+\delta f(x)$$

With the constant, I obtain:

$$T(f+a)(x)=b+\delta[f(x)+a]=b+\delta f(x)+\delta a=(Tf)(x)+\delta a$$

Is my second line correct?

Comment: Yes, if you're allowed to assume $T$ takes that form.

Comment: Great, thanks! if you want to make your response formal for credit, I will choose your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f+a$ is a function that maps $x$ to $f(x)+a$. The operator $T$ is defined as a map between functions
$$T:g\mapsto Tg \\ Tg(x)=b+\delta ~ g(x)$$
So taking $g=f+a$,
$$T(f+a)(x)=b+\delta(f(x)+a)\\ =b+\delta ~f(x)+a\delta $$
Since $Tf(x)=b+\delta ~f(x)$,
$$T(f+a)(x)=Tf(x)+a\delta$$